# Understanding Azure functions cold start (Python)

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I'm running an Azure Python function and observing inconsistent performance.

### Runtimes:

1. **Local deployment:**

   1. First run: `200ms`
   2. Subsequent runs: `7-10ms`
2. **Cloud deployment:**

   1. First run: `1300ms`
   2. Subsequent runs (within a few seconds of the first run): `100-180ms`

### Context:

- A Python function creating a JWT token.
- Only one dependency module: PyJWT.
- No external calls / connections etc.

Code:

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import jwt

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info("Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.")
    try:
        post_json = req.get_json()
        email = post_json["email"]
        id = post_json["uid"]
    except ValueError:
        return func.HttpResponse("Missing info in request body.", status_code=400)
    else:
        private_key = "ABCDEFG"
        user_data = { "email": email, "id": id }
        token = jwt.encode(user_data, private_key, algorithm="HS256")
        return func.HttpResponse(token)
```

### Questions

1. What is the reason for the first run taking longer?
2. Is it cold start / why does it happen locally as well?
3. How can this delay for the initial run be reduced? Is switching from [Consumption plan to Premium plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#app-service-plan) the answer? My function is called only 200 times in a day on avg.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is cold start.Cold start can occur both locally and in the cloud. Even when running an Azure function locally, the function environment needs to be initialized before the first execution. This is because the function host, which is responsible for managing the function lifecycle needs to be started and the function code needs to be loaded.

Ways to reduce delays

.Reduce the size of your function app packages by removing unnecessary dependencies, unused code, and large assets. This will minimize the time required to load the function app when it starts up.

.Consider upgrading to the Azure Functions Premium plan, which offers dedicated resources and faster startup times.

.Use a warmup trigger. You can use a warmup trigger to preload custom dependencies so your functions are ready to start processing requests immediately.

Comment: The warmup trigger seems like the way to go but I can't find a single example of how to use it. The MS docs on it are so spare they are useless.